# How to use or in java conditional statement eg if (a or b != c)

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I want to say "if a or b !=  c", but I can't use "or".

I've tried using `||` but get error:

```
bad operand types for binary operator '||'
    if (p1 || p2 != 1)
           ^
  first type:  int
  second type: boolean
1 error
```

I understand using `||` is for boolean or something but I don't know what else to do.

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Example{

  public static void main(String[] args){

    int  p1, p2;

    p1 = 0;
    p2 = 0;

    if (p1 || p2 != 1)
      p1 = p1 + 1;
      p2 = p2 +1;
  }
}
```

`||` doesn't work, so  how what do I use to replace `||`?

Comment: `p1` is not a boolean. What does `if (p1` mean?

Comment: Note that if you don't use curly brackets on your if-statement, it will only apply to the first statement (terminated by the semi-colon). Your `p2 = p2 +1;` will be outside of the `if` and therefore will always be executed.

Comment: Do you want to say `if(p1 != 1 || p2 != 1)`?

Answer (score 4):

Both sides of the || must be Boolean.

If you are trying to say:

```
if ( (p1 || p2) != 1)
```

what you really need to say is:

```
if (p1 != 1 || p2 != 1)
```

Java can't do the transitive thing for you.  Plus I don't think you'd want it to do that--it would get REALLY confusing in the long run.

By the way, this is one of those cases where Java is WAY more helpful than some other languages by requiring a Boolean on both sides of the || (C treats 0 as false and non-zero as true, so your statement would have been fine, just not what you intended).

By not compiling Java told you right away that you had a problem, in a more lenient language your attempt would have compiled and been completely wrong (Possibly in a way that looked right enough to pass your testing too--this is where those really tough bugs come from!)

Java also told you exactly what was wrong, but it tends to take a little while to trust java enough to really study the error messages and try to figure out what they are telling you.